# Node npm not working in windows 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I installed node js on my system running a version of windows 7. While typing `console.log('Hello World!');`, it successfully returns - 'Hello World' `undefined`. But when I type in `npm help`, it returns `Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:Users\Acme11\AppData\Roaming\npm'`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How did you install node?

Comment: from its website, clicked on the 'INSTALL' button, downloaded the '.msi' file, ran the setup

Comment: Did you install as a different user? Try creating that directory and then running `npm` again.

Comment: could you show me the command here?? pls

Comment: Check to see if node is on your path. Also, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17976504/918608

Comment: @Josh C  I just saw an instruction in a certain article about a command 'path'. I typed it in the console and a number of paths ('starting from c://...') appeared. The last of which is 'c://Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm'.