# Nodemon express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, npm, nodemon

I just made a standard `express.JS` application and I am trying to use `mongoose` so I can re-run when something changes in the directories. I did not change anything in the express folder and I installed `nodemon` correctly, when I am trying to run it I get this error:

[image]

I tried to run nodemon, `nodemon ./bin/www, npm start`,..
If I try to `run node ./bin/www`, everything works properly.

I hope you guys can help me!

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js

Comment: None of their soltions work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
spawn cmd ENOENT
```

tells that cmd is not able to find nodemon. Please see this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17976504