# Nodemon installation problem using npm commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodemon

While I am trying to install nodemon module using the command

```
npm install -g nodemon
npm install nodmeon --save
```

it is giving an error

[image: nodemon install error message]

```
C:\Users\gourav>npm install -g nodemon
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\gourav\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon -> C:\Users\gourav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js

> nodemon@1.18.10 postinstall C:\Users\gourav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\nodemon\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! file C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;
npm ERR! path C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe;
npm ERR! nodemon@1.18.10 postinstall: `node bin/postinstall || exit 0`
npm ERR! spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nodemon@1.18.10 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gourav\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-23T17_48_14_331Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I have tried using both the commands "npm install -g nodemon" and "npm install nodemon --save" as shown in screenshot above   but it is showing the same error .What should i do to sort out this problem?

Comment: Or Is there any problem with new version of node as i am using 10.15.3

Comment: please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975999/i-can%C2%B4t-install-nodemon-globally-nodemon-not-recognized) I hope it can solve your issue.