# nodemon server command not working - my first full stack mern environment

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I'm following [this guide](https://medium.com/@beaucarnes/learn-the-mern-stack-by-building-an-exercise-tracker-mern-tutorial-59c13c1237a1), and I'm at the section were I need to run this code:

```
$ nodemon server
```

But I get this error:

> nodemon : The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
>   script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
>   included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + nodemon server
>   + ~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nodemon:String) [], CommandNotFoundExce
>      ption
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I changed some settings in the package.json and installed npm globally but I'll try those again if needed.

Here is my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

I've installed nodemon fine previous to the error, I get this output when i installed nodemon.

PS C:\Users\username\mern-excercise-tracker\backend> npm install -g nodemon
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon -> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js

> nodemon@1.19.3 postinstall C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon
>   node bin/postinstall || exit 0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\nodemon\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

- nodemon@1.19.3
  updated 1 package in 9.852s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975999/i-can%C2%B4t-install-nodemon-globally-nodemon-not-recognized) this might give you more insight.

Other than that 1 workaround would be to use `npx`

```
npx nodemon server.js
```

You need `npm@5.2.0` or greater. you can check your npm version by
`npm -v` in CMD