# Nodemon not install properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

i go to install nodemon globall it's display error. how i fix this?

```
C:\Users\nipuna\Desktop\nodejs>npm install -g nodemon
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\nodemon\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...^2.0.1","sinon":"^8.1'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\nipuna\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-29T07_51_50_127Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can´t install nodemon globally, "nodemon" not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975999/i-can%c2%b4t-install-nodemon-globally-nodemon-not-recognized)

Comment: The error says that there is an Unexpected character in your package.json file.

Comment: how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Install `nodemon` globally:

```
C:\>npm install -g nodemon
```

Get prefix:

```
C:\>npm config get prefix
```

You will get output like following in your console:

```
C:\Users\Family\.node_modules_global
```

Copy it.

Set Path:

Now Run the below command with the copied path:

```
set PATH=%PATH%; C:\Users\Family\.node_modules_global
```

Now Run `nodemon`:

```
C:\>nodemon .
```