# Why can globally installed npm packages no longer be found?

Tags: npm, gulp, windows-10, yarnpkg, nodemon

I have installed a number of npm commands globally such as the gulp command line interface with:

```
npm install -g gulp-cli
```

And I can see that it is installed: `npm list -g --depth=0`:

```
C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @aws-amplify/cli@4.20.0       
+-- expo-cli@3.20.1
+-- gulp-cli@2.3.0
+-- http-server@0.12.3
+-- less@3.9.0
+-- less-watch-compiler@1.13.0    
+-- nodemon@2.0.4
+-- npm@6.14.4
+-- tsun@0.3.8
+-- typescript@3.9.5
+-- vue-cli@2.9.6
+-- windows-build-tools@5.2.2
`-- yarn@1.22.4
```

But when I run any of these commands:

```
gulp
nodemon
yarn
```

I get the response that they are not found:

```
$ gulp
bash: gulp: command not found

$ nodemon
bash: nodemon: command not found

$ yarn
bash: yarn: command not found
```

This happened all of a sudden, as if I installed something that caused this in some way. This occurs regardless of the directory I am in. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling but to no avail.

I can use e.g. `npx gulp` and `npx nodemon` so I can still work, but would like to figure out why this has occurred. Does anyone have an idea what could have changed to cause this?

Comment: I home this answers your question:
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17976504/8588241)

Comment: @DavudSeferli Thanks, that answer helped me. The solution was to execute `npm config get prefix` and add the path given to my environment variables. After that all npm commands worked again. I still have no idea what happened to cause this. Interesting.